# How to restrict Edittext to some particular characters in android?

Tags: android

```
searchEdit.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 &"));
```

I used the above statement for restricting my edittext to some characters,it is working well in my Motorolo(Android 2.3),but it is showing numeric keyboard in Google nexus.

Please provide the solution.

Answer (score 6):

First try with adding the `android:digits="abcde.....012345789"` attribute.Although the `android:digits` specify that it is a numeric field but it accept letters as well.

**OR**

try this code..

```
t1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);

    t1.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
            new InputFilter() {
                public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start,
                        int end, Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend) {

                    if(src.equals("")){ // for backspace
                        return src;
                    }
                    if(src.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*")) //put your constraints here
                    {
                        return src;
                    }
                    return "";
                }
            }
        });
```

**OR**

see an useful example from [This Link](http://blog.mobile-j.de/2009/12/i-really-like-androids-edittext.html)

Comment: The link you supplied is very useful.

Answer (score 3):

Try to change the filter method of you Listener:

```
InputFilter[] filters = new InputFilter[1];
filters[0] = new InputFilter(){
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        if (end > start) {

            char[] acceptedChars = new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 
                    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
                    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '&', ' '};

            for (int index = start; index < end; index++) {                                         
                if (!new String(acceptedChars).contains(String.valueOf(source.charAt(index)))) { 
                    return ""; 
                }               
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

};
searchEdit.setFilters(filters);
```