# How to restrict single quote and double quote in edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I use editext for chat. everything goes fine. but when i enter single quote then it display's ' and when i enter double quote then it display's " so i want to restrict these two charaters.

```
  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_add_chat_afcdl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:padding="13dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:maxLength="256"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:hint="@string/chatMsgHint"
        android:textColorHint="#C3C3C8"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_add_afcdl"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restrict Edittext to some particular characters in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17113942/how-to-restrict-edittext-to-some-particular-characters-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom input filter and then set it to the editText.

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
            Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        char[] chars = {'\'','"'};
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            if (new String(chars).contains(String.valueOf(source.charAt(index))) {
                return "";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
};
edit.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
```

Comment: use i instead of index.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid double quote and single quote use following code

`public static InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned destination, int dstart, int dend) {
            String blockCharacterSet = "'\"";
            if (source != null && blockCharacterSet.contains(("" + source))) {
                return "";
            }
            return null;
        }
    };`

You can set filter to your edit text like below

`editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });`

Answer (score 0):

**You can use below code to restrict Double Quotes in EditText using Kotlin.**

**Step1: Create Global Function in your project which you can use in multiple EditText.**

```
fun restrictDoubleQuote():InputFilter{
val blockCharacterSet = "'\""

return InputFilter { source, start, end, dest, dstart, dend ->
    if (source != null && blockCharacterSet.contains("" + source)) {
        ""
    } else null
} 
}
```

**Step2: Call above function in your EditText by using below code**

```
et_package_included.filters =arrayOf<InputFilter>(restrictDoubleQuote())
```